# MS Word “Clear All Formatting” from text using “Find and Replace” dialog

Tags: microsoft-word

I have text `Hello World` with font as `Times New Roman` i apply **Heading 6** style (style has font `Arial`) by clicking on styles in Home tab and it text font change to `Arial`.

When i use **Find and Replace** to apply **Heading 6** style to text it does not change font to Arial even though text style display's as **Heading 6**.

Basically need to find way to use **"Clear All Formatting"** feature trough find and replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can clear formatting through find and replace, but you can use it to achieve the style and font that you need.

In the Find and Replace pop-up select the Replace field and insert 'hello world.
Then:
 - More > Format > Style (pick your style) > OK.
 - Select the Replace field again.
 - Format > Font (pick your font) > OK.

Now when you run find and replace it will give you the style and font you want.